# Where can I find reference images for building modeling?

Tags: modeling

I am looking into modeling some realistic houses/buildings as a collection.

This is also one of the few times google images has failed me.

I can't seem to find helpful reference images and building plans. Anyone know of a good place to find these? www.the-blueprints.com/ sadly has no category for buildings.

Thanks

Comment: cgtextures.com under the building category, might be of use for you.